# Sql query not returnig null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

1. req_docs

[image: req_docs]

and pers_docs

[image]

My sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM req_docs
LEFT OUTER JOIN pers_docs ON req_docs.doc_nid = pers_docs.doc_nid
WHERE req_docs.pos_id ="CPT"
  AND pers_docs.pers_nid = 6
  AND pers_docs.expires <= "2009-09-01"`
```

It returns only 2 rows. Which is ok, but I need also return not existing matches from pers_docs join as NULL values. Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true left join behavior! (When in `WHERE`, you get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)

```
SELECT *
FROM req_docs
LEFT OUTER JOIN pers_docs ON req_docs.doc_nid = pers_docs.doc_nid
                          AND pers_docs.pers_nid = 6
                          AND pers_docs.expires <= "2009-09-01"
WHERE req_docs.pos_id = "CPT"
```